# Google Maps API v3: is there any function to check if a coordinate is inside a province or country

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to allow the user to introduce the coordinates himself (or herself). The following code works:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" >

    var geocoder;
    var map;

    function paintCoordsInMap() {
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var lat = document.getElementById('lat').value;
      var lng = document.getElementById('lng').value;
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    }

    </script>

    (...)
</head>


<body>
    (...)
    <f:field bean="alojamientoInstance" property="lat"/>
    <f:field bean="alojamientoInstance" property="lng"/>
    <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary" onclick="paintCoordsInMap()"> find coordinates in map! </button>  
    (...)
</body>
```

**I want to check if the coordinates are inside a province (or country, for example) to launch a windows alert if not.** If not, I'll draw a square in the map containing the province (or country), copy the coordenates of the corners. A code like the following should work (more or less):

```
if (lat > 10.111 || lat < 30.1213 || lng < 40.234 || lat > 60.23423) {
    alert('it is outside the country/province!');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an option , you could do reverse geocoding, like get the address fusing `lat` & `lng`, and check if the address matches your mentioned province, such as:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(),
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {                
                //get the required address & check
                console.log(results[1].formatted_address); 
            }
        } else {
            //failed
        }
    });
```

Comment: Good idea! I didn't realize about that possibility. I'll check if that code works later :)

Comment: The answer of @geocodezip is also perfectly correct. Use one of another depending of the situation! :)

Answer (score 4):

If you have the coordinates of the borders of the province or country you want to check against, you can us the [google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly) method to determine whether the coordinates entered are inside the polygon.

> containsLocation(point:LatLng, polygon:Polygon) | boolean | Computes whether the given point lies inside the specified polygon.